# IOs Build Failed PhaseScriptExecution

Tags: xcode, build

After build (ACHIVE) xcode shows follow problem:

```
Showing Recent Messages
mkdir -p /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-aocwdxjctofousfwvkobthpifnii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/App.app/Frameworks

Symlinked...

rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --links --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" "/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-aocwdxjctofousfwvkobthpifnii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/openssl_grpc.framework" "/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-aocwdxjctofousfwvkobthpifnii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/App.app/Frameworks"

building file list ... done

openssl_grpc.framework/

openssl_grpc.framework/Info.plist

openssl_grpc.framework/openssl_grpc

sent 2177328 bytes  received 70 bytes  4354796.00 bytes/sec

total size is 2176819  speedup is 1.00

/Users/xxxx/Downloads/test-project/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-App/Pods-App-frameworks.sh: line 132: ARCHS[@]: unbound variable
```

cocapods reinstall not working..

After build (ACHIVE) xcode must work